# Lenovo g510 webcam not detected

Tags: usb, lenovo, webcam

I have lenvo g510. Cheese and guvcview don't detect my webcam.
Its my lsubs:

```
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:8000 Intel Corp. 
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:8008 Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 0bda:0129 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTS5129 Card Reader Controller
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

How to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

I was having the exact same issue on my 1 day old Lenovo G510.  At first the webcam was detected and working fine.  One time it stopped working; I rebooted and it was fine again. 
Then a few hours later it stopped again and rebooting did nothing. I got the identical results as you from lsusb - the webcam is not listed.
This morning I tried plugging in an old USB webcam and as soon as I did, the integrated webcam was recognized and work with all apps.  I had plugged the USB cam into the USB 2 port on the right side near the power. Here is my current lsusb results:

Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:8000 Intel Corp.

Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:8008 Intel Corp.

Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub

Bus 003 Device 005: ID 0bda:0129 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTS5129 Card Reader Controller

Bus 003 Device 004: ID 0cf3:3004 Atheros Communications, Inc.

Bus 003 Device 003: ID 04f2:b3bb Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd

Bus 003 Device 002: ID 04fc:05da Sunplus Technology Co., Ltd

Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

The Sunplus is a wireless mouse.  The Chicony is the webcam, but notice also the Atheros which seems to be the bluetooth. Both of these are missing in the lsusb you posted and were missing in mine as well. I had my bluetooth turned off, but at some point in this process is was turned on again - not sure how or when.

I would turn your bluetooth on/off and plug some USB devices in - see what happens cause it worked for me.  If anyone has insight as to why the above worked I'd love to hear.

Answer (score 0):

@Aaron R. - Your answer doesn't work. This is how I made my webcam (G510) work:

`useradd -G video username`

That's it. Reboot!